# React-Native Shopping Cart - Unable to pass data to Cart screen

Tags: react-native, redux, shopping-cart

I am using redux to update the cart when a user clicks the add to cart button. The data which I am dispatching is not getting received instead different array of unknown values in received when I console.log it. Below is my dispatch function

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
    addItemsToCart:(name) =>dispatch({type:'ADD_TO_CART',payload:name})
  }
}
```

this is the button handling the dispatch. it updates the count of the cart icon but can't pass the data to the cart screen.

```
<Button icon="cart" mode="contained" onPress={(name) =>this.props.addItemsToCart(name)} style={styles.btn}>
```

Comment: button onPress event doesn't return any name itself. You need to write your own onPress and get that name from the current context.

Comment: first day with redux, totally confused. could you please let me know what to change by what

Comment: I have posted one answer, check if that helps. Else post your full code to see how we can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you have some UI for cell or view as follow,

```
const renderCell = ({item}) => {
    const {name} = item;
    return (
        //Your Item UI
        <Button icon="cart" mode="contained" onPress={() =>this.props.addItemsToCart(name)} style={styles.btn}>
    )
}
```

Considering your item has name than you can access like the way I have mentioned. If you still have issue please post your whole code which contains your button.

Comment: was messing with the props from the last 2 hours and your answer did it within a min. Thanks. One more thing, when I refresh the app the cart state gets lost. In a real app, how to keep the track of this state. Currently, everything is local but later I will put API to fetch data for the products.

Answer (score 0):

There's somewhat lack of information, but I would assume that you're missing also an API request, that would put products into your shopping cart.

You're only updating local state with redux, that's why your application "knows" the new amount of items in the shopping cart. But you need also tell your backend that new items were added.

I'm pretty sure, when you get to shopping cart, it fetches data from the backend, not from redux.

Comment: current data is in the local state. I will add api on later stage, first planning to finish this react native app part.